# Conditional angularjs directive nesting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel

Let's say I have a directive on the page like so:

```
<outer inner-type="custom" ng-model="model" options="options text"></outer>
```

Does anyone know of an effective way to have it output, without re-compiling and with the ng-model reference preserved, something to the effect of:

```
<outer>
     <!-- OTHER WRAPPER STUFF -->         
     <input ng-model="model" />

     <!-- CONTROL TYPE SELECTED WITH NG-SWITCH OR NG-IF -->
     <custom wrap-type="custom" ng-model="model" options="options text"></custom>
</outer>
```

I don't want to just transclude a bunch of stuff into the directive.

**EDIT:**

Transclusion messiness:

```
<outer ng-model="model.properties.property">
    <custom wrap-type="custom" ng-model="model.properties.property" options="options text"></custom>
</outer>
```

The ng-model reference in outer is necessary for the input, and is repeated again in the inner part. In any case, I'm pretty sure this would have problems when isolate scopes become involved.

**EDIT:**
Here's a plunker with code that creates a direct edit option as an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/rXaMrL?p=preview.

Comment: Transclude sounds like the solution to me, unless the content of <outer> is always the same, in that case you make just one directive.

Comment: if not familiar with `ng-form` nesting is very helpful for validation

Comment: I recommend using a custom directive with isolated scope and using a template.

Comment: I am using templates. I don't think I'm wording this very well. I'm going to go make a plunker example and then come back.

Comment: I am fairly new to angular, but this link may be along the line of your question (about 1/2 way down) - http://www.sitepoint.com/practical-guide-angularjs-directives-part-two/

Comment: I've added the plunker.